# In PHPExcel- Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in /Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation.php

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am getting this error
In PHPExcel-  Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in /Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation.php
I did inclusion of the files as shown below in the code.

```
include ("Classes/PHPExcel.php");
require_once "Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php";
```

Plesae any body help to resolve this error

Comment: where is the error trace ? this is totally unclear question

Answer (score 0):

I updated the PHPExcel library, error resolved. Anybody facing the same issue I suggest to download the PHPExcel library again from git and replace old library with the new files. Hope this will solve the issue..
It works for me..thanks